# Call Method in Swift Extension of UIImageView from Objective-C File

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, extension-methods

I am able call extensions of UIImage in a Swift file from an Objective-C file.

But for some reason, I cannot call the following method on an extension of UIImageView. Is there some issue with UIImageView, is my syntax off or what could be wrong?

```
extension UIImageView {
    /// Retrieve the scaled size of the image within this ImageView.
    /// - Returns: A CGRect representing the size of the image after scaling or nil if no image is set.
    func getScaledImageSize() -> CGRect? {
        if let image = self.image {
            return AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: self.frame);
        }

        return nil;
    }
}
```

Code in Objective-C file:

```
 CGRect myRect = [self.imageView getScaledImageSize];
```

Gives 'no visible interface for UIImageView declares the selector getScaledImageSize' error

Comment: Why do you have `With` at the end?

Comment: That was a variant I tried that didn't work either. Have changed back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension isn't visible because Swift optionals don't really exist in Objective-C.  Also, because `CGRect` is a structure type and not an object type, it can't be represented as `nil` in Objective-C.

Changing your method to something like this would be one potential solution to your problem:

```
extension UIImageView {

    @objc
    func getScaledImageSize() -> CGRect {

        // ...

        return .zero;
    }
}
```

Note that you need to annotate the method with `@objc` to properly expose it to Objective-C.

From the [Swift 4.2 Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html):

> The concept of optionals doesn’t exist in C or Objective-C. The nearest thing in Objective-C is the ability to return nil from a method that would otherwise return an object, with nil meaning “the absence of a valid object.” However, this only works for objects—it doesn’t work for structures, basic C types, or enumeration values. For these types, Objective-C methods typically return a special value (such as NSNotFound) to indicate the absence of a value. This approach assumes that the method’s caller knows there’s a special value to test against and remembers to check for it. Swift’s optionals let you indicate the absence of a value for any type at all, without the need for special constants.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three things you need to fix.

In your Objective-C file, you need to add the following `import` statement:

```
#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"
```

where "ProductModuleName" is the name of your project.

You need to add the `@objc` attribute to your extension class:

```
@objc extension UIImageView
```

You need to change the method to return a non-optional value. Here is a suggested implementation:

```
func getScaledImageSize() -> CGRect {
    if let image = self.image {
        return AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: self.frame)
    }

    return CGRect.zero
}
```